# Storing data in QSharedMemory

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedmemory

I'm trying to store four 'double' vars and an 'int' var in a shared memory.

`QSharedMemory::data()` offers a pointer to the memory that was set aside with `create(int size)`. My question is: **How can I appropriately join and deep copy that data onto the shared memory so I can access any of it's elements on another program for read/write?**

The only similar thing I saw was by placing the values in a `QString`. Is that the right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
struct SharedData {
  double fourDoubles[4];
  int andAnInt;
};

QSharedMemory shared_mem;
shared_mem.create(sizeof(SharedData));
SharedData* p = static_cast<SharedData*>(shared_mem.data());
p->fourDoubles[0] = 1.0;
p->andAnInt = 42;
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return `40` for the struct because of the padding? 4 doubles + one int would give a size of  `36` on a 64bit machine.

Comment: You sir, are a genius! I used the same static cast to read the data from another instance. So simple :D

Comment: @RawN And...? I'm not quite sure what you are driving at. How does the exact value of `sizeof(SharedData)` matter for anything, be it 36 or 40 or otherwise?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OP wanted to reserve memory for four doubles and one int and not a struct. Your `create` reserves a space for a structure which is 40.